# Font used in Microsoft Surface pro boot screen

Tags: fonts

When a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 or 4 is booting the text "Surface" appears in the middle of the screen.

[image: Surface boot screen]

Which is the font used for that text?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it probably is verdana

www.myfonts.com